# Returning empty enumerable as property in Linq query result in error

Tags: c#, linq

To boost performance in retrieving data from the database, I want to create a query based on certain conditions. My code that creates the query is very complicated so I will try to give a simple example that I think will be enough to explain the problem.

I have an entity, for example a car. For this car I want to retrieve all options that are installed in it. I already have the configuration for this type of car in memory. So when I know that no options are available, I do not want to query the database for the installed options. All the data should be retrieved in one query to the database.

The code I have so far

```
IQueryable<Option> optionsQuery;
if  (typeOfCar.ConfiguredOptions.Any())
   return from context.Options select new Option{...};
else
   return Enumerable.Empty<Option>().AsQueryable();

var cars = from car in context.Cars
select new Car
{
   Model = car.Model,
   Options = optionsQuery.Where(...)
}
```

When I execute this query and options are available I get data from the database. However, when no options are available Entity Framework throws the following error:

**Unable to process the type 'Option', because it has no known mapping to the value layer.**

I can't seem to find any information on what this error means exactly or why it is thrown. Can someone please help me?

Comment: at which line the error occurs ?

Comment: Read following article from msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810286.aspx

Comment: You are trying to execute `Enumerable.Empty` in the context of a query on `context.Cars`, which requires translation to SQL and sending to the database, that can't happen for `Enumerable.Empty`. How about trying an expression like `context.Options.Take(0)` instead?